# Adding emphasis to "you"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Consider the following situation.

I'm with two friends. Alice is a bad driver. Bob is not. Bob says to me, "why don't you give Alice the keys and let's go home". I say to Bob, "why don't I just give them to *you*".

Here, emphasis is, not the other person, but you (the one I'm speaking to).

I thought of 要不我给你自己 and 要不我给你本身.

This is an abstraction of something that really happened to me. I realize that using 直接给你 is probably the best way to emphasize in this case. But is there any other way to do it?

Comment: 为什么不把钥匙给你,你来开车呢？

Comment: You don't have to add any word.
You can just emphasize directly with the tone.
Increase and extend the sound of 你.
为什么我不直接把钥匙给你...呢？

Answer (score 1):

In your context, I'd probably say: 我把钥匙给你不更好吗？ or 我觉得给你更合适.